# Flask webpage not displaying newline on output

Tags: python, html, flask

When adding \n to my output variable, no newline is being added on the webpage.
In my app.py my page looks as follows(for example purposes, I took out user input):

```
(@)app.route('/update-form', methods=["POST"])
def update_form():
 output=str()
 output += "hostname updated successfully "
 output += "\nhostname 2 updated successfully"
 return render_template("update-success.html", output=output)
```

Then my update-success.html looks as follows:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}{{title}}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
    <p>{{ output }}</p>
  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

The output on my webpage does NOT include a new line, just text as follows on one line:

```
 hostname updated successfully hostname 2 updated successfully
```

Is this an issue with my Python or with my HTML? Any insight would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed `<p>{{ output }}</p>` to `<pre>{{ output }}</pre>` to get the pre-format